# Getting Class of type parameter from implementing class

Tags: java, generics, reflection, type-variables

Lets say I have some class in Java that implements `List<T>` called `Foo` that extends it with `String`, how can I get the type variable of the `List`(which is in this example is `String`)? [Just to know before I go and implement this myself, P.S. I am sure that springframework can do this]

NOTICE that this could be done because `Foo` class metadata contains the generic super class and interfaces and not the same as wanting to know the type inside `new LinkedList<String>()`

NOTICE that using `((ParameterizedType)Foo.class.getGenericSuperClass()).getActualTypeArguments()[0]` is not good enough for my needs(see the code below: `Foo` and `Bar`)

Code that shows what I want:

```
// java.util: interface List<T> { }

interface TypeList<A, T> extends List<T> { }

interface Foo extends List<String> { }

interface Bar extends TypeList<Integer, Long> { }

Class<?> getTypeParameter(Class<?> fromClass, Class<?> superTypeWithTypeVariables, int indexOfTypeVariable) {
    // ...
}

// Foo -> List<String> -> List<E> -> E is #0
assertEquals(String.class, getTypeParameter(Foo.class, List.class, 0))
// Bar -> TypeList<..., Long> -> TypeList<..., T> -> List<T> -> List<E> -> E is #0
assertEquals(Long.class, getTypeParameter(Bar.class, List.class, 0))
```

The implementation needs to go over all the class hierarchy and use ParameterizedType and TypeVariable interfaces, and some other staff.

But this question is off-topic because I asked what library implements this(see https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Library requests are off-topic.

Comment: @JornVernee: This is not a library request.

Comment: @SLaks This kinda is

Comment: @JornVernee Can you show me where Thay say that its not allowed? and how do I delete the question? and what should I do?

Comment: @SLaks is library request a request to tell me about a library?

Comment: A library request means a request for a library that does something.

Comment: So, this is a library request...

Comment: anyway I don't think any library can do this with pure java as this cannot be done even with reflection with the definitions of interfaces and classes above, however maybe this can be done  with aspect frameworks or bytecode manipulation but I'm not sure

Comment: by the way when you have 50+ reputation you can access chat where you can ask about libraries on the respective channel

Comment: @niceman This can be done with reflection. The `String` parameter is hard-coded into the class file, and available at runtime.

Comment: @IdoSorozon Here is a list of things that are off-topic: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic Which includes: _"Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource..."_.

Comment: We could be a little more flexible with XY problems that explicitly ask for a library, that are really asking "how can I do this?" Edited question to reflect this.

Comment: @AndyThomas, I Know How to do this, I need to iterate over all the class hirarcey using `getGenericSuperClass` and `getGenericSuperInterface` and when the `Type` is `ParameterizedClass` I need to get The `TypeVariable` and match the indexes and the names from the `ParameterizedType` and the `getRawType`, It is a grate hustle and can not be done simply withe the code you linked, see the class `Bar`

Comment: @AndyThomas please remove the duplicate tag, as It is not a duplicate(I explained in the question)

Comment: @JornVernee my bad, thanks for clarification

Answer (score 0):

You can use my utility `GenericUtil`, see it [here](https://github.com/XDean/Java-EX/blob/master/src/main/java/xdean/jex/util/reflect/GenericUtil.java).

Use the following method

```
public static Type[] getGenericTypes(Type sourceType, Class<?> targetClass)
```

It can infer any generic type even it's not explicit.

In you case you can do

```
getGenericTypes(Foo.class, List.class) // {String.class}
getGenericTypes(Bar.class, List.class) // {Long.class}
getGenericTypes(Bar.class, TypeList.class) // {Integer.class, Long.class}
```

Even you can do

```
interface Baz<T> extends TypeList<T, Long> {}
getGenericTypes(Baz.class, List.class) // {Long.class}
getGenericTypes(Baz.class, TypeList.class) // {T, Long.class}
```